# Problem with XSLT rendering HTML

Tags: xslt, sitecore

I am writing an XSLT file to output some HTML onto a web page (using Sitecore CMS). I am running into a problem with the following:

`<a href="../videos/video.flv" class="videolightbox jackie-hover" data="{width:400,height:200}" title="Title goes here">Text goes here</a>`

This causes the following error:

`Expected token '}', found ':'.  {width -->:<-- 400,height:200}`

Can anyone tell me how to fix this issue?

Thank you,

b3n

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the braces are used as a shortcut to evaluating an XSLT function when inside an attribute.

They are called "Attribute Value Templates":

> Attribute value templates in XSLT are
>   the XPath expressions that appear in
>   curly braces in attribute values.
>   Without this extremely convenient
>   shortcut, we'd be forced to use the
>   xsl:attribute instruction whenever we
>   needed to dynamically compute an
>   attribute's value.

You can escape them by using `{{` and `}}`.

This makes your snippet read:

```
<a href="../videos/video.flv" class="videolightbox jackie-hover" data="{{width:400,height:200}}" title="Title goes here">Text goes here</a>
```